# How to select row in telerik grid after grid rebind method?

Tags: telerik, grid

In my grid, one row was selected then I rebind that grid using grid.rebind() method. Now how can I select the same row which was previously selected before rebind.

I have tried with below code, but not able to select that row.

```
var selectedRow = $("#abcgrid tbody tr.t-state-selected");
var abcgrid = $("#abcgrid").data("tGrid");
    abcgrid .rebind();

selectedRow.addClass("t-state-selected");
```

Also tried

```
var selectedRow = $("#abcgrid tbody tr.t-state-selected");
var selectedRowID = ($(selectedRow)[0]).cells[0].innerHTML;
var gridRows = $("#abcgrid .t-grid-content tbody > tr");
               if (gridRows != null) {
               gridRows.each(function (index, row) {
                  if (row.cells[0].innerHTML == selectedRowID ) {
                     $(row).addClass("t-state-selected");
                   }
               });
              }
```

Both code doesnt work. Please guide me to select that row. Am i misssing something.
Note - their is no javascript error.

Answer (score 0):

If your row order doesn't change you can use do:

```
var selectedRow = $("#abcgrid tbody tr.t-state-selected");
console.log(selectedRow)
var indexSelecedRow = selectedRow.index();
console.log(indexSelecedRow )
var abcgrid = $("#abcgrid").data("tGrid");
    abcgrid .rebind();

var trs = $("#abcgrid tbody tr");
console.log(trs)
selectedRow = $("#abcgrid tbody tr").eq(indexSelecedRow);
console.log(selectedRow )
```

If grid content changes then every row shoud have a hidden column with an unique id parameter. You can then save this id parameter and use it after rebind.

Comment: Simon, thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it doesn’t work. Grid row is not selected

Comment: Well a little more effort from your side is needed then. I updated my answer, can you please append console output to your post. And please to this in Firefox/Firebug.

Comment: And please post HTML of your grid... so all in `<div id="abcgrid" class="t-grid">...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your efforts. I resolved this issue by writing my code on .OnRowDataBound() client event. I kept my selectedID variable as hidden and then in .OnRowDataBound() method, i wrote below lines

```
var selectedRowID = $("#hdnSelectedID").val();
    if selectedRowID != null && selectedRowID != '') {
        if (e.dataItem.ID == selectedRowID ) {
            e.row.className = "t-state-selected";
        }
    }
```

i think issue was with rebind() method, anyways thanks for the help.